# Find unknown value in matrix given $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have this matrix here 
$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    r & -4 & -6 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

with unknown value of $r$. I want to find this value so that $AX=0$ is true. What I have done so far is set up $3$ equations:

$$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0$$

$$4x_1+5x_2+6x_3=0$$

$$rx_1-4x_2-6x_3=0$$

At this point, I am unsure how to proceed, as if I continue following Cramer's rule and set up determinants, I would get $0$ to be values for $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Try row reduction and split into two cases: $r = -2$ and ...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

If the determinat is not zero the only solution to the homogeneous system is $(0,0,0)$
If you make the determinant $0$ then you have non zero solutions as well.
Is there a value for $r$ to make determinant $0$?

Comment: If I take the determinant to solve for x1,x2,x3 by, for example, subbing in 0 for all x1 values, it is 0 regardless of what happens to r

Comment: Of course you always have the zero solution. The question is that is it possible to find an $r$ which results in other solutions as well.